# Remove trailing newline from %N format specifier in git-log

Tags: git, git-log, git-notes

Is it possible to easily trim the newline when displaying a note with %N with `git log`?

I would like to include metadata about a commit by adding it with git-notes and viewing it with something like:

```
git log --format=format:'%h [%N] %an %s %D'
```

This seems much cleaner than creating commit messages with meta-data prefixed as is common practice these days, but it seems that there is always a trailing newline on the note.

Any suggestions on how to easily remove it without filtering through external tools?

Comment: Sigh. "We will end the annotation by a newline anyway" https://github.com/git/git/blob/2807bd2c10606e590886543afe4e4f208dddd489/notes.c#L1288-L1309   Looks like there is no convenient way to do this at the present time.

Comment: This could be accomplished if the metadata was in a trailer (in the commit message) instead of a note.

Comment: @Guildenstern Brilliant!  Using a trailer is definitely cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%N%-C()`.

`%N` you know. The `-` in `%-C()` means "strip immediately-preceding newlines if this is empty", and the empty color spec `C()` is empty.

From comments:

OP was using `%<(20,trunc)%N`, and notes by default have an explicitly-encoded trailing newline that the formatter does not strip—so a ten-byte note will have a newline eleventh byte and then the fixed-width will pad that out to 20 bytes with spaces . . . and `%-C()` will see the immediately-preceding space and do nothing.

One workaround for this OP found: use `%>(20,trunc)` instead, short notes will be right-aligned so the trailing newline will always appear there.

Another was [suggested by @Guildenstern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76120184/remove-trailing-newline-from-n-format-specifier-in-git-log/76133983?noredirect=1#comment134266179_76120184) in a comment on the question: use a trailer instead, whose value doesn't notionally include the embedded trailing newline.

`git notes` will supply any "missing" trailing newline to an added note, even from a file; to create a no-trailing-newline note yourself you have to create the blob manually and create it with the premade object, but even then `git log`'s formatter will add it back. So it looks like rj is pretty much the only option if you want to format the data in a fixed-width field and keep the flexibility advantage notes offer over trailers.

Comment: This works well with just `%N`, but behaves a bit strangely with `%<(20,trunc)%N%-C()`.  If the note does not fit in the width but gets truncated, the newline is stripped.   But if the notes fits completely, the newline is not stripped.

Comment: The same issue happens when truncating with a trailer using `[%<(10,trunc)%(trailers:key=meta,valueonly)%-C()]`.   Perhaps I'm using `trunc` incorrectly.

Comment: Some testing says the newline is part of the notes text, not added by `git log`, so it looks like the fixed-width processing is adding spaces *after* the newline, making it no longer a trailing newline.  You could postprocess for it, `%<(20,trunc)%N%xff | sed -Ez 's,(\n *)?\xff,,g',` yes?

Comment: Adding filters is doable, but is an extra layer of complexity I'm hoping to avoid.  I'm trying to find a simple solution to encourage people to stop doing this: https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0-beta.2/  Something like `%-*C()` would be nice (strip all preceding trailing whitespace), but does not seem to exist yet.

Comment: It does seem to me metadata that could usefully fit in such a short fixed field is a better match for trailer tags, as [@Guildenstern suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76120184/remove-trailing-newline-from-n-format-specifier-in-git-log/76133983?noredirect=1#comment134266179_76120184).

Comment: Yes, trailers certainly seems more appropriate.  And `%>()` instead of `trunc` works well with `%-C()`  Thanks!

Comment: @WilliamPursell “I'm trying to find a simple solution to encourage people to stop doing this:”—I’m glad to hear it. :·) I don’t like how that standard front-loads the metadata so much (and the metadata itself is of limited value outside of automatic version bumps). I hope you’re able to convince people. :·)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like current `git` does not support this, but the following patch seems to work:

```
diff --git a/notes.c b/notes.c
index 02f1aa39ae..21001b2261 100644
--- a/notes.c
+++ b/notes.c
@@ -1306,7 +1306,9 @@ static void format_note(struct notes_tree *t, const struct object_id *object_oid
                if (!raw)
                        strbuf_addstr(sb, "    ");
                strbuf_add(sb, msg_p, linelen);
-               strbuf_addch(sb, '\n');
+               if (!raw) {
+                       strbuf_addch(sb, '\n');
+               }
        }
 
        free(msg);
```

Comment: Note that this patch removes *all* newlines from the note.  For my immediate purpose, this is fine since the relevant notes are all single line, but this is not a viable solution.

Comment: Upvoted for the hacking spirit :·)